# Find all Triplets that sum to zero

Tags: kdb

To find triplets in a list I used below combinations function. It's working as expected.
Could you please suggest any other optimized function to identify triplets in a list in kdb.

```
q)l:0 -2 5 -3 2
q)comb:{[N;l]$[N=1;l;raze .z.s[N-1;l]{x,/:y where y>max x}\:l]}
q)r where (sum each r:comb[3;l]) = 0
-2 0  2
-3 -2 5

q)j:-2 6 1 3 -1 -4 0
q)r where (sum each r:comb[3;j]) = 0
-2 -1 3
-1 0  1
-4 -2 6
-4 1  3
```